# Class methods won't call each other from another module

Tags: python, class, methods, module

I've started learning python and currently working on making a simple Sudoku game.

I have 2 modules sudoku.py and sudoku_GUI.py

sudoku.py contains one class - Board and it's purpose is to solve the game based on an input.

solve method, in order to generate solution, needs to call other methods:

```
def solve(self):

    empty_fields = self.find_empty()
    if empty_fields == []:
        return True

    self.init_rows_columns_squares()
    row, column = empty_fields[0]
    square = 3 * (row//3) + column//3
    valid_numbers = list(set(Board.number_arr) - (set(self.rows[row] + self.columns[column] + self.squares[square])))
    valid_numbers.sort()

    for i in valid_numbers:
        if not self.is_valid(empty_fields[0], i):
            return False
        self.insert_number(empty_fields[0], i)

        if self.solve(): 
            return True

        self.insert_number(empty_fields[0], 0)
    return False
```

And this works just fine when it is called from its own module.
However, when I try to call it from Sudoku_GUI:

```
import sudoku

def solve_board(self, board):
        board.solve()

board_1 = sudoku.Board(sudoku.board)
solve_board(self, board_1)
```

It doesn't work, solve method gets called and it won't call other methods as it does in its own module. 
Obviously, I could solve it in first module and just import solved board, but since I'm learning I want to know why this happens.

If someone could explain this to me, I would be very greatful. Thank you!

Comment: what is the error you see?

Comment: There is no error, it runs, just won't call self.init_rows_columns_squares() and other I tested it by putting print("method_name") in every method and it just prints "solve"

Comment: paste your whole code to https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and send short link here

Comment: Ok, will do, just a sec

Comment: Does it work correctly if everything is in a single file?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wSkx25SfR3/
Please don't mind the singleton I know it is of no use, was just practicing

Comment: @Barmar haven't tried that, i will now

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: I didn't try to call the GUI part, but your `Board` class is working

Comment: where did you call `solve` method?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I just tried to put all in single file and still same
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t7ySHgfxNw/ -> call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you wrote, i understand you are calling your functions in a wrong way! you only use `self` keyword when you are writing code in a class. outside the class you don't need to write `self` when you call the class methods.

i will rewrite your code in order to work :

```
>>> import sudoku
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> class test_gui:
...     def solve_board(self, board):
...         board.solve()
...
>>> board_1 = sudoku.Board(sudoku.board)
>>> gui = test_gui()
>>> gui.solve_board(board_1)
>>> pprint(board_1.board)
[[1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 2, 3, 8, 5],
 [2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1],
 [3, 7, 9, 5, 8, 1, 4, 6, 2],
 [4, 3, 7, 9, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6],
 [5, 8, 1, 6, 2, 7, 9, 3, 4],
 [6, 9, 2, 4, 3, 8, 1, 5, 7],
 [7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 9, 5, 4, 8],
 [8, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9],
 [9, 6, 5, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: @ Mohsen_Fatemi Nicely spotted, but I do not think that is the issue, because that call would raise exception of some kind, if I am right?
I have scanned my code now, it is a typo. I will correct that now.
Sorry about that and thank you for time you are commiting to my issue.

Comment: yw, it does not raise exception btw. if you see this as a true answer mark it as answer. thanks.

Comment: Marking now, you helped me find the solution. Just found that insted for "" I was looking for 0s in IF which makes sense in console version but in GUI I want blanks.
Thanks once again!